# FTP installation of WordPress

Tags: ftp

The client am working with want a website built and I discovered the site use for hosting. The problem I am having is that they want a WordPress site.  What I am used to is installing WordPress of the domain in question and then start developing. But in this case they only want to provide a FTP login. Wouldn't they still have to provide the cpanel login information so I can install WordPress using this hosting provider or should I ask them to install a WordPress and provide you the WordPress admin login details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP login is more than enough to install wordpress. You just need to upload your wordpress's root folder content (not root folder itself) via FTP and then open your site's admin section via browser something like this `http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/`. Then you will see wordpress installation step. Follow that steps and your wordpress installation is done.

**NOTE** If you are uploading wordpress from local or from other domain (not fresh setup) then don't forget to change database name, username, password, host in `wp_config.php` available in root folder of wordpress.

Following steps must be done only after you have a database ready to install wordpress because on installation you need to specify database name, username and password. And database can't be created with FTP.

Comment: So once I use FTP to install it, I'll have the regular login, is that what you're saying?

Comment: If you have done installation in local then you don't need to worry because Installing in local or installing via FTP is same. Like we place wordpress folder in `httpdocs` in local then we open url (`localhost/site/wp-admin`), same goes to FTP. Upload and open site url (`ursite.com/wp-admin`). There is no extra step in installing via FTP than local.

Comment: that is actually not true, you need access to cpanel to create the DB if it is not created yet

Comment: @Mark Kaplun Yes ofcourse a database is required. I have already mentioned in **NOTE** in my answer to change name of DB. In my answer I have shown only FTP's way of installation but for database creation access of `phpmyadmin` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, installing wordpress via the hosting admin with a one click install is both faster and less error pron. It also give the hosting company a chance to deploy whatever optimizations they might have for wordpress on their servers.

In any case you will need access to "cpanel" to create the DB.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is enough (and frankly, preferred) to install wordpress. It's only a couple steps, and there are a million resources online to walk you through it. [Here's one](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).

You don't need cpanel access to do the install, but you WILL need credentials for a few services. If the client cannot provide those credentials, they may wish to give you cpanel access instead.

**Requirements**

- FTP username and password
- MySQL host, username and password
- MySQL database created for wordpress
- Access to phpmyadmin would be ideal, but not required

If your client can't provide that, gently offer to help by either walking them through it on the phone, or getting access to take care of it yourself.

Simply upload all the unzipped files to the web root directory (this depends on your host. It may be ~/public_html, or ~/web, or something else). Then point your browser to the domain, and the wordpress install script will guide you through the setup.

As for your other question: once you install wordpress, you'll be given a username and password to login to wp-admin. That's all you'll need to setup everything on the backend.

Good luck!